# Printing as the pages available in telerik tabstrips using c# mvc4

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, printing

Hi We are using the Telerik tabstrips for the tabbed content. 
Those tabbed content should come as print preview for the print option directly as we got in the webpages. it should be like, each and everytab in one page, its like, tab1--page1, tab2--next page.. like that it should be printed. Suggest me what is the effective way can be used to do the same...like through any jquery, or controller method can be used.. or anythng like this..